# Finding the center of mass of a convex hull

Tags: python, triangulation, convex-hull

I'm trying to find the center of mass of a convex hull. This convex hull is constructed by the triangulation of a set of scattered data points, in particular a Delaunay triangulation, and each point has a value, *i.e.* w = f(x,y,z). The mass of the convex hull is given by the function f, which is treated as the density of the solid. This function is unknown, so it has to be interpolated from the values w at each point.

I'm a beginner with Python, so I was wondering which would be the best way of finding this center of mass. I was trying with 2D surfaces first. `scipy.interpolate.griddata` interpolates the data, but then I don't know how to integrate the function in order to compute the center of mass (I need to integrate the interpolated function f over the domain of the convexhull). Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the points 2D or 3D? They look 3D, but you mention 2D

Comment: This is a pair of geometry problems. (1) If I give you a tetrahedron with known corner weights, find the center of mass and the total mass. (2). If I give you a pair of blobs of known mass and center of mass, find the mass and center of mass of the system. (1) is the input to (2). (2) lets you accumulate the total mass over all the tetrahedra.

Comment: @MadPhysicist in the main problem the points are 3D, but first I was playing with 2D as a toy example to see if could make that work. Which Python package do you recommend for doing this? ir order to find the interpolated function

Comment: I'm working on an answer. It might take a little while because of other commitments, but it's mostly pen, paper, and numpy.

Comment: That's assuming you have a package like scipy to do the convex hulls and triangulation already.

Comment: Thank you! Yea, I'm currently using scipy.spatial.Delaunay for the triangulation

Comment: I have about 3/4 of of a very detailed answer. Working on the center of mass part right now. Still about a day out

Comment: Still working on this BTW. Just taking time is all

Comment: Thanks mate. Im working on understanding the different functions in the Scipy packages needed for this. Much appreciated!

Comment: Mostly just multiply and divide :)

Comment: I'm big on closed form solutions